# Include a UTF8 character literal in a [UInt8] array or Data

Tags: swift, swift3

I would like something similar to:

```
let a = ["v".utf8[0], 1, 2]
```

The closest I have figured out is:

```
let a = [0x76, 1, 2]
```

and

```
"v".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)! + [1, 2]
```

Note: Either `[UInt8]` or `Data` is an acceptable type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String`'s `UTF8View` is not indexed by an `Int`, rather it's own `String.UTF8View.Index` type, therefore in order to include the first byte of a UTF-8 sequence of a given string in your array literal, you could use its `first` property instead:

```
let a = ["v".utf8.first!, 1, 2] // [118, 1, 2]
```

If there's more than one byte in the sequence, you can concatenate the UTF-8 bytes with an array literal simply by using the `+` operator:

```
let a = "".utf8 + [1, 2] // [240, 159, 152, 128, 1, 2]
```

Also note that your example to concatenate a `[UInt8]` to a `Data` could be shortened slightly to:

```
let a = "v".data(using: .utf8)! + [1, 2] // Data with bytes [0x76, 0x1, 0x2]
```

Comment: I choose `["v".utf8.first!, 1, 2]`

Answer (score 3):

There is a specific `UInt8` initializer (introduced in Swift 2.2+):

```
let a = [UInt8(ascii:"v"), 1 ,2]
```

Answer (score 3):

*(Some addendums to the already posted answers; regarding `UnicodeScalar`'s in particular)*

---

In you question you've used a literal `"v"` as the base instance to be converted to `UInt8`; we don't really know if this is a `String` or e.g. `UnicodeScalar` in your actual use case. The accepted answer shows some neat approaches in case you are working wit a `String` instance.

---

In case you happen to be working with a [`UnicodeScalar`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/unicodescalar) instance (rather than a `String`), one answer has already mentioned the [`init(ascii:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/uint8/1538725-init) initializer of [`UInt8`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/uint8). You should take care however, to verify that the `UnicodeScalar` instance used in this initializer is indeed one that that fits within ASCII character encoding; the majority of `UnicodeScalar` values will not (which will lead to a runtime exeception for this initializer). You may use e.g. the [`isASCII`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/unicodescalar/1641111-isascii) property of `UnicodeScalar` to verify this fact prior to making use of the initializer.

```
let ucScalar: UnicodeScalar = "z"
var a = [UInt8]()
if ucScalar.isASCII {
    a = [UInt8(ascii: ucScalar), 1, 2]
}
else {
    // ... unexpected but not a runtime error
}
```

Another approach, in case you'd like to encode the full `UnicodeScalar` into `UInt8` format (even for `UnicodeScalar`'s that cannot be single-byte ASCII endoded) is using the [`encode(_:into:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/utf8/2294501-encode) method of [`UTF8`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/utf8):

```
let ucScalar: UnicodeScalar = "z"
var bytes: [UTF8.CodeUnit] = []
UTF8.encode(ucScalar, into: { bytes.append($0) })
bytes += [1, 2]
print(bytes) // [122, 1, 2]

// ...
let ucScalar: UnicodeScalar = "\u{03A3}" // Σ
var bytes: [UTF8.CodeUnit] = []
UTF8.encode(ucScalar, into: { bytes.append($0) })
bytes += [1, 2]
print(bytes) // [206, 163, 1, 2]
```